# R: rearranging vectors based on rank

Tags: r

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(MEMORY1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), MEMORY2 = c(2, 2, 2, 
2), MEMORY3 = c(3, 3, 3, 3), MEMORY4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4), MEMORY5 = c(5, 
5, 5, 8), MEMORY6 = c(6, 6, 8, 5), MEMORY7 = c(7, 8, 6, 6), MEMORY8 = c(8, 
7, 7, 7)), .Names = c("MEMORY1", "MEMORY2", "MEMORY3", "MEMORY4", 
"MEMORY5", "MEMORY6", "MEMORY7", "MEMORY8"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
> dat
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
1       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
2       1       2       3       4       5       6       8       7
3       1       2       3       4       5       8       6       7
4       1       2       3       4       8       5       6       7
```

Suppose I have the above `data.frame`, and each entry is the rank of the MEMORY item. So for the second row, `MEMORY1` had rank 1, `MEMORY2` has rank 2, ... `MEMORY8` has rank 7, etc.

I want to reorder each row of the `data.frame` based on the rankings of the MEMORY items.

Row 1 would simply stay the same `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

Row 2 should be `1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7` because `MEMORY8` is ranked before `MEMORY7`

Row 3 should be `1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6`

Row 4 should be `1 2 3 4 6 7 8 5`

How can I write code so that once I pass in `dat` the output would look something like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    8    7
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    7    8    6
[4,]    1    2    3    4    6    7    8    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t(apply(dat, 1, order))
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
2    1    2    3    4    5    6    8    7
3    1    2    3    4    5    7    8    6
4    1    2    3    4    6    7    8    5
```